# Extracting only specific color from image with scanner artifacts

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I have the following problem:

I want to extract only the color of a blue pen from scanned images that also contain grayscale and black printed areas on a white page background.

I'm okay with disregarding any kind of grayscale (not colored) pixel values and only keeping the blue parts, there won't be any dominant color other than blue on the images.

It sounds like a simple task, but the problem is that through the scanning process, the entire image contains colored pixels, including blue ones, even the grayscale or black parts, so I'm not sure how to go about isolating those parts and keeping only the blue ones, here is a closeup to show what I mean:

[image: Scanned black line with RGB artifacts]

Here is what an image would look like for reference:

[image: Input image example]

I would like the output to be a new image, containing only the parts drawn / written in blue pen, in this case the drawing of the hedgehog / eye.

So I've tried to isolate an HSV range for blue-ish colors in the image using this code:

```
img = cv.imread("./data/scan_611a720bcd70bafe7beb502d.jpg")
img_hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# accepted color range for blue pen
lower_blue = np.array([90, 35, 140])
upper_blue = np.array([150, 255, 255])

# preparing the mask to overlay
mask = cv.inRange(img_hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
inverted_mask = cv.bitwise_not(mask)
mask_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(inverted_mask, (5, 5), 0)
ret, mask_thresh = cv.threshold(mask_blur, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# The black region in the mask has the value of 0,
# so when multiplied with original image removes all non-blue regions
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv.imshow("Result", mask_thresh)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

However the result is this:

[image: Result image with attempted color isolation method]

Many parts of the picture that are drawn in black such as the cloud image are not removed since as mentioned, they contain blue / colored pixels due to the scanning process.

Is there any method that would allow for a clean isolation of those blue parts of the image even with those artifacts present?
The solution would need to work for any kind of image like this, the one given is just an example, but as mentioned the only color present would be the blue pen apart from the grey/black areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the opposite- search for black parts first and then do some erosion around this black mask and remove all around it before you are searching for the blue. The "main" color in the cloud is still black so you can play around this.

Answer (score 1):

You should realign the color planes of your scan. Then you're at least rid of those color fringes. I'd recommend scanning a sheet of graph paper to calibrate.

This is done using OpenCV's `findTransformECC`.

Complete examples can be found here:

- https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d93/samples_2cpp_2image_alignment_8cpp-example.html
- https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/

And here's specific code to align the color planes of the picture given in the question:

https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/b8867b46f320eae17f4b2684416c79ea

(all it does is split the color planes, call `findTransformECC` and `warpPerspective`, merge the color planes)

[image: before and after color plane alignment]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried printing a sheet of graph paper and then scanning it and using the scanned file and the original print file for the alignment after adjusting it so that they have the same dimensions and roughly align (although it was impossible to actually align the grids since the scanned one is so warped).

It didn't really work out, the result is unchanged in terms of color plane misalignment (https://imgur.com/a/b96Y275) I'm assuming the misalignment is too large like what the article you linked suggests may cause problems.

Comment: I don't mean align the scan to its ideal source file (as you've seen, printing introduces additional deformation), but align the scan's color planes to each other. feel free to share those pictures themselves, instead of screenshots.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah I misunderstood how it works my bad, so when aligning my image with the scanned graph paper as a template it changes the image slightly but I think not significantly.

I used this code from the article you linked:
https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/
With my original image as im1 and the graph paper scan as im2

Result is this:
https://i.imgur.com/6m6JCPw.jpg

Screenshot of the difference:
https://imgur.com/a/cHhaIif

Comment: you *don't* use different pictures for this. you use the *color planes* of the *same* picture. here's what I managed to achieve with findTransformECC (red/blue to green channel, which is the best of all three) https://imgur.com/a/ThCkOGa

Comment: Thanks for your patience with this, as you probably noticed I'm not that experienced with image processing.

However, I don't really see a significant difference with your output there and my original scan (https://imgur.com/wx9kxJl - the output image from your comment on the right, my original scan is on the left) in terms of color pixels near black areas, am I still missing something?

Comment: you are looking at the first picture in my imgur album, which is *your* image, for reference. look at the *second* one.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now I think. I did notice that in some cases, for example with the graph paper grid there are still a great amount of color pixels where there should be black ones, but the script you provided is very helpful to improve the overall image quality of the scans which is fantastic - although in order to actually properly isolate the blue parts I had to go with the suggestion in the other answer to get it to work properly.